# Why does the MVC appends aspx to the view names

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my controller I defined:

```
const string KList = "list.cshtml";
```

I call the Action method:

```
public ActionResult All()
{
    var view = Empty();

    var model = new Model(); // some other code to get the model

    view = PartialView(KList, model);
    return view;
}
```

here is the view:

[image]

And I get this error:

> **System.Web.HttpException:** 'Error executing child request for handler
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.'
>
> **InnerException:** InvalidOperationException: The partial view 'list.cshtml' was not found or no view engine supports the searched
>   locations. The following locations were searched:
>
> ~/Views/Communication/list.cshtml.aspx
>
> ~/Views/Communication/list.cshtml.ascx
>
> ~/Views/Shared/list.cshtml.aspx
>
> ~/Views/Shared/list.cshtml.ascx

Why is it appending aspx and ascx to the view file?

Comment: There is something missing here, if you call `return View()`, it won't search for "list", unless you do something like `return View(KList)`. Then, you'd need to change `KList` to be "list" instead of "list.cshtml".

Comment: @Alisson , just corrected it. thanks for pointing out.

Comment: You're welcome, I answer which some more details, if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view engine will take the parameter you passed to `View()` and look inside your controller's folder for a file with the same name, with supported extensions, like:

- cshtml (part of razor engine)
- aspx (ASPX engine)
- ascx (User Control)

So you don't need to explicitly pass the extension for the `View()` overloads which take the view name as first argument. Just change:

```
const string KList = "list.cshtml";
```

to

```
const string KList = "list";
```

I suggest reading [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/aspx-view-engine-vs-razor-view-engine/) explaining the diference about both view engines (Razor and ASPX).

Comment: so it appends all the file extensions itself even if we mention one? that is so stupid

Comment: @SimpleFellow yes, the view engine follows a sequence, until it finds one that matches. It starts looking in the Controller's folder, if it doesn't find, it will look inside the `Shared` folder inside `Views`.

Comment: @SimpleFellow if you dont like it, write your own view engine.  It's not hard.

Comment: @SimpleFellow The MVC uses all view engines by default. If you don't like this behavior in the `Application_Start` method in the `global.asax.cs` add this: `ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());`

Comment: @SimpleFellow as soon as the `.cshtml` file exists, it won't keep looking for `.aspx` and other extensions, that would be unnecessary. But if it doesn't find it inside the obvious folders (controller's views folders and shared), it'll assume you are trying to use some other file extension, which is strange to use in one same project, but it's possible and there are situations people might need this (like migrating from webforms to MVC, but trying to keep some webform pages together with the new mvc project).

Comment: @S.Akbari , that is interesting! I think I would try that